# HTML blur image on hover w/ text?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a portfolio website for school and I'm trying to make it so that a large photo (which is also a link) blurs and has text appear ontop of it when hovered over. I'm almost there, but I'm having a few issues:

1.) I can't for the life of me figure out how to center the text on the photo completely. I've tried playing with width percentages and padding and margins, but the text is never perfectly centered. I want it so that it acts like the header and navigation--centered & responsive to window resizing.

2.) My blur transition seems to be a bit off because it works fine when hovering over the photo, but when I hover off the photo, instead of transitioning out of the blur, it just kind of splits out of the blur immediately with no transition. Here is my code for the following:

```css
.photowrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.photo1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo1:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.photo1:hover .img1text {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img1text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="photowrapper">
  <a href="design.html">
    <div class="photo1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=%20" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="100%" />
      <div class="img1text">DESIGN</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I've also attached two images for reference:
[Image before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC9IV.jpg)
[Image after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzI1t.jpg)

I hope I've provided enough info. Many thanks to anyone who's able to help!

Comment: did you want the text to show top center or at the center point of the image

Comment: You should note that none of those vendor prefixes are needed anymore and most haven't been needed in many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove redundant markup - you need a link with an image, and a text container:

```
<a class="photo1">
    <img>
    <div class="img1text">text</div>
</a>
```

The `.img1Text` is absolutely positioned, and you need to set it's [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block) (2) by setting `position: relative` (or any other non static position) on `.photo1`.

To center `.img1Text`, you can use the [transform method](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#both-unknown):

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

To have the transition work on both enter and exit move it to the `img` style declaration:

```
.photo1 img {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.photo1 {
  position: relative;
  /** set as the txt con**/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo1 img {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.photo1:hover img {
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.photo1:hover .img1text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img1text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a class="photo1" href="design.html">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/150" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="100%" />
  <div class="img1text">DESIGN</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) I can't for the life of me figure out how to center the text on the photo completely. I've tried playing with width percentages and padding and margins, but the text is never perfectly centered. I want it so that it acts like the header and navigation--centered & responsive to window resizing.

To center text you must ensure the image and the text block have the same width, and then use `text-align: center;`. If the text is offset a bit (as in your photo), it probably means that the widths aren't the same, or that there is padding and/or margin happening as well. Without seeing your code live, it would be difficult to determine.

> 2.) My blur transition seems to be a bit off because it works fine when hovering over the photo, but when I hover off the photo, instead of transitioning out of the blur, it just kind of splits out of the blur immediately with no transition. Here is my code for the following:

Add the same `transition` rule to the `.photo1` class. When you add transition to `.photo1:hover`, the transition is applied to the mouse on. Without `transition` on the base class, it will transition immediately when you mouse out.

Think of the class and the hover as two different states. If you want both to share the same transition effect, both must have the rule applied.

Comment: any way to fix the text centering of the word "Design". as it stands, it centers at the beginning of the word instead of the center of the word.

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire set a maximum width for the container which holds the image and text (`.photo1`). The text has `width: 100%;` so on smaller viewport sizes, the text will probably be centered on the image, but once the viewport is expanded beyond the width of the image, the text will continue being centered on the viewport but the image won't be. You could solve this with `display: block; margin: auto;` on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Blur transition problem, move blur statements to the element not the element on hover:

```
.photo1 img {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.photo1:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

Text centered problem:

```
.photo1 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Reference material:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=display+flex&topic=api&topic=css&topic=canvas&topic=html&topic=http&topic=js&topic=mobile&topic=apps&topic=svg&topic=webdev&topic=standards&topic=webext&topic=webgl

codepen: https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/XxZbMm

Answer (score 0):

Use position relative to class **.photo1** as given below.

```
.photo1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-self: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;/*newly added*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.photowrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.photo1 {
     margin: 0 auto;
    align-self: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.photo1:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.photo1:hover .img1text {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img1text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="photowrapper">
  <a href="design.html">
    <div class="photo1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=%20" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="100%" />
      <div class="img1text">DESIGN</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

You should make parent div to `position:relative` then child to `position:absolute`